# Error: DllPlugin: supply an Array as entry

Tags: electron, webpack-3

I have a project developed starting from this [repository](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate). I wasn't on top of updating my app with their updates which is what I should have done but I would update libraries depending on my need for a new version. I updated my app about two weeks ago or so with all their updates. I merged all the conflicts and fixed the errors until everything was working as expected.

In that repository, they updated to webpack 3 and started using dll as a way to build the app faster during development. My issue is that I can't build my dlls and the error that I'm getting is this: `Error: DllPlugin: supply an Array as entry`. Here is a minimal repository https://github.com/hyalkaf/DLLPluginError that is a copy of their repo but with an additional window. This minimal repo doesn't have much extra code except for a few lines to create an extra window.

To give context to this error, Here are the files that I think are relevant in the minimal repo.

webpack.config.base:

```
entry: {
    bundle: './app/index.jsx',
    worker: './app/worker.jsx',
    reportImage: './app/reportImage.jsx'
  },
```

webpack.config.renderer.dev.js

```
entry: {
    bundle: ['react-hot-loader/patch', `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/`, 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.jsx')],
    worker: ['react-hot-loader/patch', `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/`, 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', path.join(__dirname, 'app/worker.jsx')]
  },
```

webpack.config.renderer.prod

```
entry: {
    bundle: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.jsx'],
    worker: ['babel-polyfill', './app/worker.jsx']
  },
```

Then I have an extra html file called worker.html as well as worker.js under app directory. I also added a new window to main.dev.js file.

To reproduce the error, fork or clone the repo and run: npm run build-dll

Github issues that could are/could be related:

1. https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/1199

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking a question, since you link to a [post](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/1199) that contains a solution to the problem.

In case someone else stumbles upon this question, the workaround solution is to wrap *all* `entry`s in brackets.

Using the sample code provided in the question, `webpack.config.base` should be changed accordingly:

```
entry: {
    bundle: ['./app/index.jsx'],
    worker: ['./app/worker.jsx'],
    reportImage: ['./app/reportImage.jsx']
  },
```